# Consuming Service Bus Sessions without a Queue/SubscriptionClient?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, messaging, servicebus

I'm attempting to create a messaging layer on top of the Service Bus .NET client library, giving me the ability to switch Service Bus out for something else if needed.

In my "receiver" class I can use the *MessagingFactory*'s *CreateMessageReceiver* method to get a generic *MessageReceiver* that will work for both queues and subscriptions. My class can just be given the entity path and the *MessagingFactory* figures it out. However, from what I can tell, this generic receiver cannot deal with session-enabled queues and subscriptions - I must use a *QueueClient* or *SubscriptionClient* object to accept sessions.

Is there a way to receive from sessions without using a *QueueClient* or *SubscriptionClient* object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MessageSession` is an equivalent of a `MessageReceiver` so from a processing perspective you can have a abstraction that takes in a `MessageReceiver` or a `MessageSession`. The way these are obtained is indeed different from the `MessagingFactory.CreateMessageReceiver` approach since you need to invoke that from a `QueueClient` or `SubscriptionClient` because the `MessagingFactory.AcceptMessageSession` does NOT take a URI path but actually returns sessions from the entire namespace (supported on with Service Bus on premise).